# Small-Angle X-Ray Scattering of Bulk Polymers

Tags: polymers, crystal-structure, x-ray-diffraction

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to get useful information from SAXS of polymers when the system is not dilute?

This is the type of data we're working with:
[image: 1D SAX Pattern of a Polymer Film]

My understanding is that since there's no plateau at the beginning we can't use the correlation function to get parameters like Lc.

I'd really appreciate if anyone has any thoughts on how to alternatively calculate this!

Comment: What are the axes on your figure $A(q)$ vs $q$ ?

Comment: The more relavant details your provide, the more relevant answers arrive. and vice versa.

Comment: So sorry, the axes are momentum transfer (q) and Intensity. So it's a plot of I(q). This sample is a semicrystalline polymer film of ~20% degree of crystallinity by WAXS